# Firefox Extension, get a reference to the loaded document using browser.contentDocument

Tags: firefox, document, xul

I want to write a simple firefox extension.

How can I get a reference to the loaded document object in a browser window? For example, how can I access the document in this html page loaded here on stackoverflow? According to the vague mozilla development center I can use browser.contentDocument, but it is not working for me.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="sample" 
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script type="application/x-javascript">
 function change(){
  //var doc = document.getElementsByTagName("browser")[0].contentDocument;
  //var doc = document.browser.contentDocument;
  var doc = browser.contentDocument;


  var body = doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var text = doc.createTextNode("blah");
  body.appendChild(text);
 }
</script>
<statusbar id="status-bar">
  <statusbarpanel id="my-panel" label="click me" onclick="change();"  />
 </statusbar>
</overlay>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you read that the variable is browser.contentDocument, since it's listed in several spots to be [`content.document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Frequently_Asked_Questions#Accessing_the_document_of_a_webpage_doesn%27t_work) (but I'm linking to the FAQ).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code

under accessing content document

"Assume you have a document loaded in a <tabbrowser>, <browser>, or <iframe> element inside your document. You can use browser.contentDocument to access that document"

Comment: In that case, browser is referring to the <browser> element which you'd have to get a reference from.  You should mark my answer as correct if it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Variable for accessing content of current displayed document: `window.content.document`